# Rebuild NSMenuItems in StatusBar

Tags: cocoa, dynamic, nsmenuitem, nsmenu

I'm trying to have a dynamic number of NSMenuItems in a Statusbar app. Right now I'm reading in a list in the `awakeFromNib`. But this only happens once.
What do I have to do to rebuild my NSMenuItems while the applicaiton is running?
Should it happen in something like `-(void)menuNeedsUpdate:(NSMenu *)menu`?
Can somebody give me a push in the right direction please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `NSMenuDelegate` on your header file (the .h file), like this:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate,NSMenuDelegate>{
}
```

(or in the header file of the class that you need the selector to be called)

Comment: I think there where several things wrong. I had to add NSMenuDelegate and I did not reference some outlets. I fixed it by snooping around other peoples code. :) Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Use `– addItem:` `– removeItem:` methods.

```
NSMenuItem *test = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"test" action:@selector(test) keyEquivalent:@"a"];
[[StatusItem menu]  addItem:test];
```

Comment: Hi,
I'm already adding items this way from a list. My problem is to rebuild the menu when changing that list. I'm trying to run do something in `- (void)menuNeedsUpdate:(NSMenu *)menu {` but it does not get called. You can have a look into my code here https://github.com/fabiantheblind/Shortcuts/blob/master/Shortcuts/tmnAppDelegate.m#L111

Comment: [[StatusItem menu] setDelegate:self];

Comment: Sorry I'm to new to this. I don't understand your hint

Comment: set status menu delegate. thn - (void)menuNeedsUpdate:(NSMenu *)menu method will get called.

Comment: Hm. That gives me: property 'delegate' not found on object of type 'NSStatusItem *'

Comment: [[self.statusBar menu] setDelegate:self];

Comment: Okay. That does compile but I'still don't get anything from menuNeedsUpdate. I need to read some more to understand this